# New GTK ListBox widget used in gnome-control-center with python

Tags: python, gtk, gobject

I want to use the new GTKListBox and GTKListBoxRow used by Gnome in their Control Center using python 3 and gobject.

Here's a picture of the widgets I'm talking about:

[image: Gnome Control Center GTK List Box]

Looking the code I figured it out that the widgets were that ones, but maybe I'm mistaken.

Any way I could use them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're just normal GtkWidgets so you shouldn't have a problem using them. However they are new in Gtk 3.10 which will have a stable release towards the [23 September](https://wiki.gnome.org/ThreePointNine). In the mean time you can build it from the git sources or if you're lucky your distribution might have some development packages (e.g. arch linux has the gtk3-git in the aur) If you decide to build it yourself I'd recommend using [jhbuild](https://wiki.gnome.org/Jhbuild) as once you've set it up it makes it easy to stay up to date with the latest git changes. The documentation for the development version of gtk is [available online](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/)

Comment: Oh thanks! I'm using Arch and seing the widgets in the current control center I thought that it was already available in gtk, but as you pointed was included to gtk 3.10. Thanks